# Is there a DTD for XPage source?

Tags: xml, xpages, dtd

With whatever little knowledge I have of XML I know that we can associate a DTD with XML file which defines all the valid elements, its attributes and where they can appear.

Is there any such DTD associated with XPage source code defining all the elements and its attributes? Where does it define tags like `xp:view`, `xp:panel`, `xp:button` and so on along with its associated properties? So I am looking for a file with content something like `<!ELEMENT xp:panel ......>`

Comment: On the Page Generation tab of the XSP Properties (in Designer 9), there are options to set both the encoding and the HTML Doctype - is that what you mean?

Comment: @DragonsMind: Oh no! I am looking for DTD of the actual XPage source not generated page. Where does it define tags like `xp:view`, `xp:panel`, `xp:button` and so on?

Comment: I think you may mean namespace then. The DTD would normally refer to the HTML or XHTML type (e.g. HTML 4.01 DTD) but the namespace (XMLNS) would define the unique elements and attributes. So we have xp for standard XPages, xe for Extension Library controls, xc for Custom Controls etc. These are defined as attributes in the xp:view at the top of the page e.g. <xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">.

Am I getting closer?

Comment: DTD can handle namespace (https://www.informit.com/library/content.aspx?b=STY_XML_21days&seqNum=51). So I am looking for a file with content something like `<!ELEMENT xp:panel .....`. Does this clarify?

Comment: Okay - last shot and then I'm out of suggestions. I don't think there is a DTD file explicitly like that but I suspect you might be looking for something like the *.xsp-config files. If you're creating a control using the Extensibility API, you specify the Namespace, Java package, description and properties etc and name of the control etc. in an XML config file. See http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPages_configuration_file_format for more info.

Comment: DTD is old school... XML is almost always validated via a schema now instead. But, as Toby indicates, there's no way for IBM to define an inclusive schema since the platform is extensible by every customer. What are you trying to accomplish by having a DTD / schema?

Comment: @TimTripcony: It was actually out of curiosity! DTD could give insights on how elements can be structured, some of which I may not be aware of. And the argument "there's no way for IBM to define an inclusive schema since the platform is extensible by every customer" does make sense :)

Comment: Tim, a schema covers one namespace. When you extend XPages you use your own name space. So the core and extlib schemata (that's the proper plural for schema) could be determined. It actually could be generated as renderer

Comment: One could actually use Designers component registry to build a DTD on the fly for which components are available based on the namespaces specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No There is not a DTD for xpages source as anyone can add there own tags through an extension library.

Comment: You can even define your own namespace in any custom control... no extension library required.

Comment: Your argument does make sense as anyone can add there own tags so there would be no DTD :)