# Content assist in Domino Designer - extension library

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib, domino-designer-eclipse

I'm new in xpages development and I'm facing this issue.
I have installed the updateSiteOpenNTF-designer.zip from ExtensionLibraryOpenNTF-901v00_13.20150611-0803 release.
When working on xpage in the source view I'm getting only `<xp:this...>` tags as suggestions via Content assist.
But it would be much helpful to have all possible `<xp:..>` tags included in the Content assist, like '', `<xp:eventHandler...>`, etc.
Within the Extension library there is documentation with all these possible tags in html format. My question is:
is there a way to transform this documentation into another format (i guess xml) and included it somehow into Content assist of Domino Designer?

I'm using Domino Designer 9.0 which is based on Eclipse.

Thank you very much for any useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this question [Is there a DTD for XPage source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982911/is-there-a-dtd-for-xpage-source).

To elaborate, the `xp:...` tags are core components, not part of the Extension Library. Those tags all start `xe:...`. It will probably need some kind of xml schema documentation to be created and for you to point to. I did something similar for themes https://github.com/paulswithers/xpages_theme_dtd. Creating the schema for that was not particularly challenging, but there will be more elements and attributes for this. I don't believe anyone has created a schema up until now, and I don't think it's something that can be auto-created from Javadoc documentation (which is available on the web).

Once available, you might need to remove the dtd specification at the top before compiling, as you do for themes.

Comment: Hi Paul. thx for your answer. Will look into it and try to create something like you suggested.